# How to correct result with Union All

Tags: mysql, tree, binary-tree, union-all

I am fetching the result of Union All but Only 1 query is running.

```
select user_leftside as SId  from tbl_user inner join (select @sid:=(select group_concat(user_leftside,',',user_rightside) from tbl_user where find_in_set(user_id, @nsid)) , @nsid:=@sid as fset from tbl_user, (select @nsid:='first_left_child',@sid='')v )gr on find_in_set(user_leftside,fset) where user_leftside <> ''
UNION ALL 
select user_rightside as SId  from tbl_user inner join (select @sid:=(select group_concat(user_leftside,',',user_rightside) from tbl_user where find_in_set(user_id, @nsid)) , @nsid:=@sid as fset from tbl_user, (select @nsid:='first_left_child',@sid='')v )gr on find_in_set(user_rightside,fset) where user_rightside <> ''
```

How can i get the result with Union All. This is tree related query

Comment: Single query works fine separately

Comment: Use different variable names inside those two subqueries: use of variables in MySql queries is always risky: the order of evaluation is not guaranteed. These subqueries might even perform evluations in parallel and so you must avoid spillover of variable values from one to the other.

Comment: @trincot, Special thanks to you, query runs like a charm. How can i marked your comment to solution. ?

Comment: I posted it as an answer. Now you can tick it ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use different variable names inside those two subqueries.

The use of variables in MySQL queries is always risky: the order of evaluation is not guaranteed. These subqueries might even perform evaluations in parallel and so you must avoid spillover of variable values from one to the other.